# creating trigger which will insert into table from view

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have view LIVE_MATCHES (home,away,comp_name) and 
table MATCHES (priority ,sport,sub_list)

I need to create a trigger that inserts in TABLE from VIEW after the view is updated or inserted (doesn't matter) and to check that unique column (sub_list) in table Matches isn't already inserted. Only need to insert from view is comp_name, sport and priority are fixed variables.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LIVE_MATCHES_TO_MATCHES 
        instead of insert ON LIVE_MATCHES 
       for each row
              declare
       p_priority number:= 1;
       p_sport number:=0;
       begin
         insert into MATCHES (sub_list , priority , sport, created) 
         select :old.comp_name , p_priority, p_sport,sysdate
         from dual
          where not exists (      
         select 1 from MATCHES 
        where sub_list = :old.comp_name);
       end;
```

I edited trigger so it is compiled now without errors but it does not insert into table MATCHES.

What am I doing wrong in this trigger.

Comment: It appears you are using SQL*Developer. Please confirm.

Comment: yes that is true..

Answer (score 1):

## SQL*Developer

SQL*Developer has a bad habit of interpreting the `:new` and `:old` identifiers of a trigger as run-time BIND variables.  Usually, a window will pop up asking for a value for the BIND variable `new` and/or `old`.

[image: SQL*Developer asks for BIND value for "new"]

## Workaround

One workaround is to edit the `TRIGGER` directly by going trough `Connections`.

A simple "recompile" works.
[image: Editing the TRIGGER code]

Comment: I run trigger by toad so it went without that problem... but still it does not insert into table I changed the trigger a little bit

Comment: `:old` does not exist for `INSERT` statements.  See section `Triggers for Building Complex Updatable Views` for example.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS770

Answer (score 1):

Your new version works for me if I just change the `:old` to `:new`, as Michael Kutz pointed out. When I insert something into `LIVE_MATCHES` with a value for `comp_name` that does not exist in `MATCHES` in the column `sub_list`, a new row is inserted into matches with the value of `comp_name` in `sub_list`.

Comment: i edited code, but still not inserting into table

Answer (score 0):

That insert into matches should work. I can't spot anything wrong. As indicated, it could be a side effect of SQL Developer ...

However the select that follows will not work. You cannot use `:new` that way - not in a select statement. `:new` represents the values of the columns you used in the original insert into the view.

In addition you cannot write a singleton select (that is what you do) without including an `into` to specify the variables that receive the results.

If you want to find out whether anything exists in MATCHES with a given value for a column, then you can do something like that:

```
select count(*)
into p_count
from matches
where comp_name = :new.sub_list;
```

and define `p_count` as one more variable. If it is 0, then no rows with that value exists.

But the question is: why do you do this ? In your code you do not use the result of that select ... Or do you want to do this check **before** the insert ?

**EDIT:**

Just to confirm. I tried your scenario and everything works fine. I did the following:

1. Defined an external table over a CSV file
2. Defined a view on that external table
3. Defined an "instead of insert" trigger on that view

Everything works just fine. The insert on the view is correctly handled by the trigger.

Here is the complete example:

The CSV file is like this:

```
 2|Los Angeles|CA|3485398|2|-118.411201000|34.112101000|
 3|Chicago|IL|2783726|3|-87.684965000|41.837050000|
 4|Houston|TX|1630553|4|-95.386728000|29.768700000|
 5|Philadelphia|PA|1585577|5|-75.134678000|40.006817000|
 6|San Diego|CA|1110549|6|-117.135770000|32.814950000|
 7|Detroit|MI|1027974|7|-83.102198000|42.383100000|
 8|Dallas|TX|1006877|8|-96.765249000|32.794151000|
```

Here is the external table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE us_cities_ext (
  id              NUMBER,
  city            VARCHAR2(42),
  state_abrv      VARCHAR2(2),
  pop90           NUMBER,
  rank90          NUMBER,
  longitude       NUMBER,
  latitude        NUMBER
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_files
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" (
      id,
      city,
      state_abrv,
      pop90,
      rank90,
      longitude,
      latitude
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('us_cities.dat')
);
```

The view on the external table:

```
create or replace view us_cities_v as
select * from us_cities_ext;
```

The trigger:

```
create or replace trigger us_cities_v instead of insert on us_cities_v
for each row
begin
  insert into us_cities (id, city, state_abrv, rank90, pop90)
  values (:new.id, :new.city, :new.state_abrv, :new.rank90, :new.pop90);
end;
/
```

This trigger inserts into another table (US_CITIES) with a similar structure to the external table.

Trying it out. Insert into the view:

```
SQL> insert into  us_cities_v values (1001,'Bismarck','ND', 68981, 231, -100.74869, 46.766667);
1 row created.
```

The row was correctly inserted in the target table:

```
SQL> select * from us_cities where id >= 1000;

    ID CITY           STATE_    POP90  RANK90
------ -------------- ------ -------- -------
  1001 Bismarck       ND        68981     231

1 row selected.
```

Comment: I do this because I have another external table but i cant do triggers on it. I must do it via view of that external table and to insert into matches..

Comment: I was not questioning the use of a trigger. I meant specifically: what is the purpose of the select after the insert into the table ? What is the point of that since you do not use the result of that select ? Now I see you replaced your INSERT VALUES() with an INSERT ... SELECT and that makes more sense.

Comment: after insert into table I use function which will get all sub_list from MATCHES table

Comment: So is the trigger working now ?

Comment: I searched and what i read is that you cant create trigger on view or external table ... i created job and created procedure which will insert into table

Comment: I guess that makes sense: external tables are read-only anyway. But I would have thought an "instead-of" trigger on a view over an external table would be possible. Where did you see that restriction mentioned ?

Comment: I tried instead of insert, could not insert into table. so i choose job/procedure

Comment: I just did a quick test. I defined a view on top of an external table, an "instead of"  trigger on that table. Tried an insert. Everything works fine. Not sure what you are doing. It looks to me like some syntax/logic error in your trigger. But the basic mechanism works just fine.

Comment: I added the full example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but my trigger could not trigger on the view ... now I have problem with job sometimes it gets broken i do do insert into table by procedure called by job ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979799/oracle-procedure-insert-into-table-from-another-table/49996533?noredirect=1#comment87046448_49996533

Comment: IMO your problems have to do with the logic you try to apply. It has nothing to do with the fact that logic is executed in a trigger over a view over an external table (which works just fine). I am still not clear about what it is that you actually want to achieve. Maybe showing some example data both for the external table and the internal table would help people here giving sound advice. Also the big picture of the business problem you want to solve.